# Table Rates CSV format for zip codes

Tags: magento, rate

My CSV file have a format like this picture 
[image]

I import successfully. But in cart page, I fill postcode 1500 then get estimate quote, nothing happen. I had to fill 1500-2170 then get quote, it show Price 500.

No shipping method show if I use postcode 1500 in my address. How to make it show or estimate by fill 1500 instead of 1500-2170.

Answer (score 6):

The `Zip/Postal Code` on the Table Rates table does not accept a range of zip or postal codes. It only accepts the exact codes.

That is the following are valid entries for the `Zip/Postal Code` column:

- 1500
- 1501
- 1502
- etc.

If you want to enter a range of zip or postal codes you need to install a module to allow this functionality. There is a module WebShopApps MatrixRate that adds this functionality: 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/webshopapps/extension/604/webshopapps-matrixrate--the-original-multiple-table-rate-solution--certified-bug-free

Answer (score 2):

The `Zip/Postal Code` does not allowed area range. You just given a exact code. Ex: Hyderabad: zipcode is: **500001**. Once you try this method.